# How to use Vite plugin with Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, vite, storybook

I am building React and TypeScript programs with Vite and using the Vite plugin [vite-plugin-dynamic-import](https://github.com/vite-plugin/vite-plugin-dynamic-import)  to handle dynamic imports. This makes npm run dev, npm run build work fine.

However, when I use Storybook, npm run storybook, npm run build-storybook give me an error.
None of the errors that Storybook outputs seem to be useful either. Is there any solution to this problem?

```
...
✓ 331 modules transformed.
✓ built in 2.77s
[vite:build-import-analysis] Parse error @:38:1
...
ERR! Error: Parse error @:38:1
ERR!     at parse$e (file:///xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-abb4f102.js:16485:355)
ERR!     at Object.transform (file:///xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-abb4f102.js:46496:27)
ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) <br>
ERR!  Error: Parse error @:38:1
ERR!     at parse$e (file:///xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-abb4f102.js:16485:355) 
ERR!     at Object.transform (file:///xxx/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-abb4f102.js:46496:27) 
ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) { <br>
ERR!   idx: 2271, 
ERR!   pos: 2271,
...
ERR!   hook: 'transform',
ERR!   code: 'PLUGIN_ERROR',
ERR!   plugin: 'vite:build-import-analysis',
```

"@storybook/react-vite": "^7.1.0" 
"vite": "^4.4.4" 
"vite-plugin-dynamic-import": "^1.5.0"

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dynamicImport from 'vite-plugin-dynamic-import'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    dynamicImport(),
  ],
})
```

.storybook/main.ts

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-vite',
  },
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/react-vite",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
};
export default config;
```

Comment: Did you follow their guide? https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.0/react/builders/vite

Comment: Yes. I added viteFinal(config), but didn't work well.

Comment: I advise you to create a repo in github and put a link (to it) here.